Can you turn off Upload & Install Fonts in FSE?
Is it possible to turn off the Upload and Install Fonts from within WordPress fonts panel?


yes, it's covered in the blog post on wordpress.org that introduced it https://make.wordpress.org/core/2024/03/14/new-feature-font-library/#how-to-disable-the-font-library
